# Putting rows of pandas dataframe into list form

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe of the form

```
    T1  T2
0   A   B
1   C   D
2   B   C
3   D   E
4   F   A
```

I would like to generate another pandas dataframe that lists each of the unique items in T1 and T2 has its own row, and has a column with the name of that unique item and a column with a list of the items it shared a row with in the original dataframe. For example, in this case I would be looking for something of the form:

```
    Name    List
0   A   [B, F]
1   B   [A, C]
2   C   [D, B]
3   D   [C, E]
4   E   [D]
5   F   [A]
```

Can someone suggest a proper pandonic (like pythonic but for pandas :)) way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, swap columns and use `pandas.DataFrame.columns`:

```
df2 = df.copy()
df2.columns = df.columns[::-1]
new_df = pd.concat([df, df2])
new_df.groupby("T1")["T2"].apply(list).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  T1      T2
0  A  [B, F]
1  B  [C, A]
2  C  [D, B]
3  D  [E, C]
4  E     [D]
5  F     [A]
```

Comment: This answer seems to have the same problem as the below answer -- Let's say there's duplicate rows. [A B], [A B], and [B A]. In my application, I would want the list for A to contain [B, B, B] (3 occurences of B, not necessary adjacent)